# Significant battery drop/reboot, but only in cold weather (+5°C/+41°F) with camera - expected behaviour or battery defect?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, camera, weather

*Disclaimer: This is not a duplicate, I've looked at [these questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery%20drop) but none are applicable(temperature) or provide an adequate answer.*

Recently I've realized that my 15 month old LG G4 seems to have an issue with the battery in cool or cold weather: dry, no significant windchill, +5°C/+41°C

**In at least 3 instances, it happened to drop from 50% or even 65% charge to zero, rebooting without warning. I've not seen issues at other times (higher temps)**

I can even reproduce this:

- Have the phone at 50% to about 70% charge
- go outside if its around 5°C
- take a couple of pictures with Open Camera.

After a couple of minutes, it will reboot and only have a fraction (<10%) of the charge, and keep rebooting if I try to take pictures.

I've tried all the "battery reset tricks" out there, but as I said above - I don't have any issues other than in the cold (+camera).

## Is this expected behaviour or should I replace my battery ?

Do I want *too much* from my smartphone ?
Should I scale back my settings to try and keep the power draw lower ?

---

Additional Information:

It's a Li-Po 3000 mAh (original) battery
Android 7.1.2 (LineageOS 14.1)
Open Camera settings: High Res (16:9 15.87 MP), 90% JPEG, GPS on, 100% display brightness, background thread, no flash
I'm also uploading the pictures to owncloud via the owncloud App ("Instant Upload") over 3G/4G

Here are [some graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlK58.jpg) from GSam Battery Monitor.
If you look at them closely, it seems to "recharge" around 5% if its in a warmer environment again.

Comment: This is really a bad question, it calls for speculation/opinion. You have 3 very specific conditions noted as necessary for the undesirable operation, if any one of those is taken out of the equation is the operation as you would expect? Meaning, if you use Google Camera instead of Open Camera, the temperature is warmer, or the battery has a better charge, this condition does not occur? If so, the answer seems pretty straight-forward, if not, then your question is not really about the problem.

Comment: @acejavelin, if I remove the temperature from the equation I don't have an issue - how is that *pretty straight-forward* ? Are you suggesting I don't use the camera in the cold ? I don't get what you mean. Also it covers all the basics [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If someone says " *ah! open camera has an issue with power draw with these settings*" then I wouldn't discard this as *opinion*, rather see it as informed fact.

Comment: Only one of your 3 questions is not purely opinion based... And the one question that is not purely opinion based still calls for speculation. I am not trying to be negative or argumentative here, just clear. And if the cold is the only real factor, that changes the question significantly. If the trifecta of conditions is required, just change the camera app because that is the easiest for you to control, that was what I meant by straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [All batteries achieve optimum service life if used at 20°C (68°F) or slightly below](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharging_at_high_and_low_temperatures)
- For Li Ion ( or Li Po) the ideal *charging* temperature is 0°C to 45°C
  (32°F to 113°F) and operating temperature is –20°C to 60°C
  (–4°F to 140°F) [Source](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures)

Based on the above, it looks like you have a poor battery given that

- It is being operated within the designed temperature range
- Unexplained sudden drop from above 50% or more to zero
- Marginal increase in charge when brought indoors

Till you get a replacement battery all I can think of by way of power consumption reduction is to delay the cloud upload (do it once it's charged / WiFi)

**Edit:** Try a different camera app. It looks like Open Camera does consume more power and show increase in battery levels after reboot as quoted [here -in particular post of 17/12/2017 which matches very closely to what OP describes](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/tickets/306/). If that doesn't help much change battery

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'll verify this in the coming days but a comment on the SourceForge link you provided "*I find that Open Camera drains my phone's battery much much faster than the built in app. I just tested it and on 20% battery I can take about 5 mins video with Open Camera before the battery is critically low. After restarting the phone the battery goes up to 17% or so, and so on.*" sounds very similar, sans the cold!

Comment: Were you able to validate?

Comment: I'm working on it !

Comment: Hi, so after some time I can confirm at least one thing: Open Camera consumes way more power than it should. I suspect, but cannot confirm: The higher power demands, coupled with an ageing battery and sub optimal ambient temperature seems to have caused this. I was unable (or unwilling) to replace the camera app, but I bought a new (and bigger) battery - which has ultimately resolved the issue. Still, I'm not happy that one app can crash my phone this way..

Answer (score 0):

My phone does this too. It's always done it, the phone (and battery) are 5 years old and everything works properly, just not when it's cold (way colder than +5°C). Maybe my battery is iffy, don't know that it is, don't know that it isn't, but since it works fine the rest of the time, I'm not losing sleep over it.

I'm calling it "normal behaviour" for my phone. As a side not, if you see a guy out and about in -20°C weather holding his phone under his armpit and cursing his battery, come over and say "Hi!".